# Making Pivot table with Multiple Columns and Aggregating by Unique Occurences

Tags: r, dplyr, pivot-table, reshape2, distinct-values

I'm having a tough time wrapping my head around this or finding a guideline online.

I have membership data. I want to be to see how many members last in a particular month before dropping their membership. I can see which month they have joined and I can see how long they've been active by looking at their transaction no (it increases by 1 each month). So if I track transaction no's for each month, I can get a waterfall of how many people joined that month and what the drop off was.

The kicker is that sometimes there are multiple transactions within a month by the same member, but I would only like to count that member once, so I would need to count that member only once.

```
Name | Joined Month | Transaction no
Adam | Jan          | 1
Adam | Jan          | 2
Adam | Jan          | 2
Ben  | Jan          | 1
Ben  | Jan          | 2
Ben  | Jan          | 3
Ben  | Jan          | 4
Cathy| Jan          | 1
Donna| Feb          | 1
Donna| Feb          | 2
Donna| Feb          | 3
Evan | Mar          | 1
Evan | Mar          | 1
Frank | Mar         | 1
Frank | Mar         | 2
```

Aggregating for distinct members with months as columns, the result would look something like this:

```
Transaction# | Jan | Feb | March
1            | 3   | 1   | 2 
2            | 2   | 1   | 1
3            | 1   | 1   | 0
4            | 1   | 0   | 0
```

Any tips or pointers in the correct direction would be very helpful. Should I be using reshape2 or a similar package? Hopefully I did not butcher the explanation or the formatting, please feel free to ask any questions.

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like your task is to 1. take distinct observations, 2. count transactions by month, and 3. reshape into a wide format. So in `tidyverse` functions (since you tagged `dplyr`), that could look like `distinct` > `count` > `spread`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a reproducible example that uses the tidyverse functions `dplyr::n_distinct` and `tidyr::spread`.

I have first represented your data as a tibble (or you could use a data frame equally well).

Next we group by `Transactionno` and `JoinedMonth` before counting distinct Names.  To get it in table format you request we use `tidyr::spread`. If you want the resulting columns in month order, ensuring your data frame has them as ordered factors would be important.

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)

x <- tribble(
        ~Name , ~JoinedMonth,  ~Transactionno,
        "Adam" , "Jan"         , 1,
        "Adam" , "Jan"          , 2,
        "Adam" , "Jan"          , 2,
        "Ben"  , "Jan"          , 1,
        "Ben"  , "Jan"          , 2,
        "Ben"  , "Jan"          , 3,
        "Ben"  , "Jan"          , 4,
        "Cathy", "Jan"          , 1,
        "Donna", "Feb"          , 1,
        "Donna", "Feb"          , 2,
        "Donna", "Feb"          , 3,
        "Evan" , "Mar"          , 1,
        "Evan" , "Mar"          , 1,
        "Frank" , "Mar"         , 1,
        "Frank" , "Mar"         , 2  

)

x %>%
  group_by(Transactionno, JoinedMonth) %>% 
  summarise(ct = n_distinct(Name)) %>% 
  tidyr::spread(JoinedMonth, ct, fill = 0)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#> # Groups:   Transactionno [4]
#>   Transactionno   Feb   Jan   Mar
#>           <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1            1.    1.    3.    2.
#> 2            2.    1.    2.    1.
#> 3            3.    1.    1.    0.
#> 4            4.    0.    1.    0.
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) xtabs** This one-liner uses base R and the input `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note below.  Note that we assume that Joined.Month is a factor with levels Jan, Feb, Mar to ensure that the output is sorted in that order (rather than alphabetically).

```
xtabs(~ Transaction.no + Joined.Month, unique(DF))
```

giving:

```
              Joined.Month
Transaction.no Jan Feb Mar
             1   1   3   2
             2   1   2   1
             3   1   1   0
             4   0   1   0
```

**2) table**  Another base R approach.

```
with(unique(DF), table(Transaction.no, Joined.Month))
```

giving:

```
              Joined.Month
Transaction.no Jan Feb Mar
             1   3   1   2
             2   2   1   1
             3   1   1   0
             4   1   0   0
```

**2a)** This would also work and is shorter but not quite as clear:

```
table(unique(DF)[3:2])
```

**3) tapply** This also uses only base R:

```
u <- unique(DF)
tapply(u[[1]], u[3:2], length, default = 0)
```

giving:

```
              Joined.Month
Transaction.no Jan Feb Mar
             1   3   1   2
             2   2   1   1
             3   1   1   0
             4   1   0   0
```

### Note

`DF` in reproducible form is assumed to be:

```
Lines <- "Name | Joined Month | Transaction no
Adam | Jan          | 1
Adam | Jan          | 2
Adam | Jan          | 2
Ben  | Jan          | 1
Ben  | Jan          | 2
Ben  | Jan          | 3
Ben  | Jan          | 4
Cathy| Jan          | 1
Donna| Feb          | 1
Donna| Feb          | 2
Donna| Feb          | 3
Evan | Mar          | 1
Evan | Mar          | 1
Frank | Mar         | 1
Frank | Mar         | 2"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", 
  strip.white = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
DF$Joined.Month <- factor(DF$Joined.Month, lev = month.abb[1:3])
```